# Centos 7: Configure ethernet for MPIO

Tags: centos7, mpio

I can't understand how MPIO uses network ports to connect to iSCSI volumes on a SAN.
How should network cards be configured? I have to use 4 network ports on the SAN and 4 on the server.
In the multipath parameters I set roundrobin 0.
Thank you

Best regards
Riccardo